# App does not register service with Consul

Tags: java, spring, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-consul

My App does not register service with Consul. I tracked the source code, the problem seems like the bind method of  AbstractAutoServiceRegistration does not invoke. If I understand correctly, the binding logic is in org.springframework.cloud.consul.serviceregistry.ConsulAutoServiceRegistrationAutoConfiguration, it defined a bean which type is ConsulAutoServiceRegistration. The ConsulAutoServiceRegistration class is extended from AbstractAutoServiceRegistration.

```
@Bean
@ConditionalOnMissingBean
public ConsulAutoServiceRegistration consulAutoServiceRegistration(
        ConsulServiceRegistry registry,
        AutoServiceRegistrationProperties autoServiceRegistrationProperties,
        ConsulDiscoveryProperties properties,
        ConsulAutoRegistration consulRegistration) {
    return new ConsulAutoServiceRegistration(registry,
            autoServiceRegistrationProperties, properties, consulRegistration);
}
```

Then a method named bind in AbstractAutoServiceRegistration is annotated by @EventListener(WebServerInitializedEvent.class).

```
@EventListener(WebServerInitializedEvent.class)
public void bind(WebServerInitializedEvent event) {
    ApplicationContext context = event.getApplicationContext();
    if (context instanceof ConfigurableWebServerApplicationContext) {
        if ("management".equals(
                ((ConfigurableWebServerApplicationContext) context).getServerNamespace())) {
            return;
        }
    }
    this.port.compareAndSet(0, event.getWebServer().getPort());
    this.start();
}
```

But I find out this method does not register in listeners because of the package of AbstractAutoServiceRegistration is start with "org.springframework." so in EventListenerMethodProcessor it has been ignored.

```
private void processBean(final String beanName, final Class<?> targetType) {
    if (!this.nonAnnotatedClasses.contains(targetType) && !isSpringContainerClass(targetType)) {
...
```

}

```
private static boolean isSpringContainerClass(Class<?> clazz) {
    return (clazz.getName().startsWith("org.springframework.") &&
            !AnnotatedElementUtils.isAnnotated(ClassUtils.getUserClass(clazz), Component.class));
}
```

What is the problem? And How can I fix it?

Comment: I knew the answer. It's Spring Boot's version not suit for Spring Cloud's. I was use Spring Boot 2.1.1.RELEASE and Spring Cloud Finchley.SR2, even they are the newest version both, but they don't work together. Now I change my Spring Cloud's version to Greenwich.RC2. It's worked.